# Python - compare nested lists and append matches to new list?

Tags: python, list, compare

I wish to compare to nested lists of unequal length. I am interested only in a match between the first element of each sub list. Should a match exist, I wish to add the match to another list for subsequent transformation into a tab delimited file. Here is an example of what I am working with:

```
x = [['1', 'a', 'b'], ['2', 'c', 'd']]

y = [['1', 'z', 'x'], ['4', 'z', 'x']]

match = []

def find_match():
    for i in x:
        for j in y:
            if i[0] == j[0]:
                 match.append(j)
            return match
```

This returns:

```
[['1', 'x'], ['1', 'y'], ['1', 'x'], ['1', 'y'], ['1', 'z', 'x']]
```

Would it be good practise to reprocess the list to remove duplicates or can this be done in a simpler fashion?

Also, is it better to use tuples and/or tuples of tuples for the purposes of comparison?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Seafoid.

Comment: How come you are getting the above output? I am getting only the following element [['1', 'z', 'x']] as the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Use sets to obtain collections with no duplicates.

  - You'll have to use tuples instead of lists as the items because set items must be hashable.
- The code you posted doesn't seem to generate the output you posted. I do not have any idea how you are supposed to generate that output from that input. For example, the output has `'y'` and the input does not.
- I think the design of your function could be much improved. Currently you define `x`, `y`, and `match` as the module level and read and mutate them explicitly. This is not how you want to design functions—as a general rule, a function shouldn't mutate something at the global level. It should be explicitly passed everything it needs and return a result, not implicitly receive information and change something outside itself.

  I would change

  ```
  x = some list
  y = some list
  match = []
  def find_match():
      for i in x:
          for j in y:
              if i[0] == j[0]:
                   match.append(j)
      return match # This is the only line I changed. I think you meant 
                   # your return to be over here?
  find_match()
  ```

  to

  ```
  x = some list
  y = some list

  def find_match(x, y):
      match = []
      for i in x:
          for j in y:
              if i[0] == j[0]:
                   match.append(j)
       return match
  match = find_match(x, y)
  ```
- To take that last change to the next level, I usually replace the pattern

  ```
  def f(...):
      return_value = []
      for...
          return_value.append(foo)
      return return_value
  ```

  with the similar generator

  ```
  def f(...):
      for...
          yield foo
  ```

  which would make the above function

  ```
  def find_match(x, y):
      for i in x:
          for j in y:
              if i[0] == j[0]:
                   yield j
  ```

  another way to express this generator's effect is with the generator expression `(j for i in x for j in y if i[0] == j[0])`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I interpret your question correctly, but given your example it seems that you might be using a wrong index:

change

```
if i[1] == j[1]:
```

into

```
if i[0] == j[0]:
```

Comment: You are correct! Thanks for pointing that out. I edited to incorporate that and showed the output.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this a lot more simply by using sets.

```
set_x = set([i[0] for i in x])
set_y = set([i[0] for i in y])
matches = list(set_x & set_y)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I didn't know that I could specify indices within set. I thought that set would only return complete matches for all contents of the list.

Comment: Good idea [to work with sets].  You should stress however that the results will differ from these of the original program, with regards to ordering and possibly to duplicate values (which may or may not matter, depending on the eventual use of the results).

Comment: @Seafoid: the indices are applied to the sublists of x and y, not to any of the sets.

Comment: You should not use [] in the the set constructors.  Removing the braces creates a generator expression, which does not need to allocate memory for an entire list.

Answer (score 1):

```
if i[1] == j[1]
```

checks whether the *second* elements of the arrays are identical. You want `if i[0] == j[0]`.

Otherwise, I find your code quite readable and wouldn't necessarily change it.

Answer (score 0):

A simplier expression should work here too:

```
list_of_lists = filter(lambda l: l[0][0] == l[1][0], zip(x, y))
map(lambda l: l[1], list_of_lists)
```

Comment: This compares the whole sublists, which doesn't seem to be what OP wanted.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this is what I would call simpler. I almost always find it nicer to use list comprehensions than filter/map with an anonymous function. For example, I think `[suby for subx, suby in zip(x, y) if subx == suby]` is (I think) exactly equivalent to your code, but a whole lot nicer to read than the `filter` and `map` version. I think `[suby for subx in x for suby in y if subx[0] == suby[0]]` is more equivalent to OP's code.

Comment: @Mike I like list comprehensions as well, though the functional approcach tempts me once in a while:-). thanks for pointing mistake, corrected now.

Comment: Using `map` and `filter` isn't really more functional than using a list comprehension.